# Best Practice for Indexing Large Number of Products on Google

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I have a client who has a large database of products. Their site has search functionality to find these products, which returns a paginated list of matches but the products themselves do not have individual pages.

The client would like to have each product indexed by Google, so that when a buyer needs a replacement part and they google the product serial code, it would drive them to their site so they can buy a replacement. The client has well over 30,000 unique product codes though.

My initial thought is to generate a page for each product programmatically, each with specific meta data, and then put in a reindex request through Google Webmaster Tools. That seems super hamhanded though.

The products are industrial in nature so it seems incorrect to handle them through Google Shopping. Is there a way to associate a database of products with a site through Google?

Comment: Are you sure it is the proper forum for this kind of question ? It doesn't look like a programmation question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming.

Answer (score -1):

Sumbit a program-generated sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools (and Bing as well). These tools will accept a .php link for the sitemap.